# Attribution when using other plugin's code

Tags: licensing

What's the proper way to show attribution when using code taken from another open source WordPress plugin?

I'd like to know both in the case of just a particular function, and even for a whole file containing many functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin should have information in it regarding the license in use.  Look in the `readme` file (could be called `README`, `readme.txt`, `README.TXT`, `readme.md`, or some other permutation), the plugin's PHP files (there will be one with a block that begins with:

```
/*
 Plugin Name: xyz
 .
 .
 .
 */
```

and that block will often contain the type of license in use.  You may also find a `License` file -- possibly `LICENSE`, `license.txt`, `license.md`, or some permutation.

The License section of the Codex page on [Writing a Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#License) states that

> Most Plugins use the GPL2 license used by WordPress or a license compatible with the GPL2.

Read up on the [GPL (GNU Public License) here](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html). (Note that the current GNU page references GPL v3, not v2.  I don't know what differences might exist between v2 and v3.)

[Markdown on Save Improved](https://wordpress.org/plugins/markdown-on-save-improved/) was forked from [Markdown on Save](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/markdown-on-save/), and includes this text [in its code](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/markdown-on-save-improved/tags/2.4.2/markdown-on-save.php):

> This software is forked from the original Markdown on Save plugin (c) Mark Jaquith

...as well as a link to the parent plugin on its Wordpress.org Plugin home page.

If in doubt, you can always try to contact the plugin's developer(s).

Comment: Thanks, I would like to know what commenting to use specifically for particular functions that are being taken from other plugins, and for a file of functions. Your example is one I'm familiar with (forking of a whole plugin).

Comment: I would suggest that Section 5 (Conveying Modified Source Versions) of the [GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) covers what you're asking about: "The work must carry prominent notices stating that you modified it, and giving a relevant date."  That said, I am not a lawyer.